# Why can't LinqPad autogenerate a context object with EF?

Tags: entity-framework, linqpad

Does anyone know why LinqPad cannot autogenerate an Entity Framework context object (like it does with Linq-to-SQL)? It seems I have to create an assembly containing an EF context and then reference the assembly in LinqPad. But I don't need to do this with L2S.

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LINQPad uses LINQ-to-SQL for automatic data contexts because it's lighter and faster. LINQ-to-SQL also generates better SQL in many cases and allows arbitrary functions in the final projection.

It wouldn't be hard, in principle, to write a driver for Entity Framework. The reason it isn't present as an option is [lack of demand](http://linqpad.uservoice.com/forums/18302-linqpad-feature-suggestions/suggestions/3057911-entity-framework).

If you wanted, you could implement EF support seamlessly as a third-party driver. The only tricky thing to implement is supporting every version of EF.

Comment: Thanks Joe. I find your comment how L2S generating better SQL is many cases hard to believe. I would think the query generator in EF is much more advanced than L2S, because Microsoft has continued to work on it over the years, whereas, I suspect the L2S generator hasn't been improved in probably four years or more.